How do I properly activate a Conda environment in VSCode?
I'm trying to activate a conda environment in VSCode, but when importing modules inside my environment I get a ModuleNotFoundError.
First when I run conda list in the terminal, the packages show up. To "activate" the environment, I selected it from Python: select interpreter in the command palette. When I use conda env list, the correct environment is starred.

In visual sudio code you can directly press cntrl+shift+P and on the top of screen you can search python interpreter and choose the right environment for your script

Sometimes, after activating a conda environment, I end up using the wrong Python version.
import sys    
print(sys.executable)

The correct path should be <CondaPath>/envs/<Env>/bin/python on Linux or <CondaPath>/envs/<Env>/python.exe on Windows.
I'm not sure why, but reopening the terminal seemed to resolve the issue.

Thx for the tip. I tried this and the path is pointing to my local python. Do you know how I can change the path?

@victorsu please don't accept this as an answer as it is not an answer

@victorsu Sorry for that, but I'm not sure of the exact reason. I just reopen the terminal and everything works fun.
